Video Recorder using MediaCodec in Xamarin.Android Produces Tiled Video Output
I am working on a video recording feature in a Xamarin.Android app using MediaCodec for encoding. My goal is to record video and save it in H.264 format. However, the output video appears tiled, as shown in the image below.
Here is my code:
using Android.Media;
using Android.Util;
using Java.IO;
using Java.Nio;
using System;
using System.IO;
using static Android.Media.MediaCodec;

namespace Record.Droid
{
    public class VideoRecorder
    {
        private const string TAG = "VideoRecorder";
        private const string MIMETYPE = "video/avc";
        private const int WAITTIME = 10000; // Adjust as needed
        private MediaCodec codec;
        private DataOutputStream dos;

        public bool SetupEncoder(int width, int height, string outputPath)
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(fileStream);
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                {
                    Log.Error(TAG, "Failed to open output file: " + e.Message);
                    return false;
                }

                MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.CreateVideoFormat(MIMETYPE, width, height);
                mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, 700000);
                mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyFrameRate, 30);
                mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyColorFormat, (int)MediaCodecCapabilities.Formatyuv420planar);
                mediaFormat.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyIFrameInterval, 5);

                codec = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType(MIMETYPE);
                codec.Configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);
                codec.Start();

                return true;
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, "Failed to set up encoder: " + e.Message);
                ReleaseEncoder();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void EncodeFrame(byte[] data, long presentationTimeUs)
        {
            try
            {
                ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.GetInputBuffers();
                ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = codec.GetOutputBuffers();
                bool sawInputEOS = false;
                int inputBufferIndex = -1, outputBufferIndex = -1;
                BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();

                inputBufferIndex = codec.DequeueInputBuffer(WAITTIME);
                if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
                    inputBuffer.Clear();
                    inputBuffer.Put(data);

                    codec.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.Length, presentationTimeUs, 0);
                }

                outputBufferIndex = codec.DequeueOutputBuffer(info, WAITTIME);
                if (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.GetOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex).Duplicate();
                    outputBuffer.Position(info.Offset);
                    outputBuffer.Limit(info.Offset + info.Size);

                    byte[] array = new byte[info.Size];
                    outputBuffer.Get(array);

                    dos.Write(array);

                    codec.ReleaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);

                    if ((info.Flags & MediaCodecBufferFlags.EndOfStream) != 0)
                    {
                        ReleaseEncoder();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, "Error encoding frame: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        public void ReleaseEncoder()
        {
            try
            {
                if (dos != null)
                {
                    dos.Flush();
                    dos.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException e)
            {
                Log.Error(TAG, "Failed to release encoder: " + e.Message);
            }

            if (codec != null)
            {
                codec.Stop();
                codec.Release();
                codec = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

The output video is tiled, as shown in the image below:

Steps to Reproduce:
Set up the encoder using the SetupEncoder method with the specified width, height, and output path.
Feed frames to the encoder using the EncodeFrame method.
Observe the saved video file.
Questions:
Why is the output video tiled?
What changes are needed in my code to fix this issue and produce a normal video?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please read [ask].  Relevant code should be included in your post, not as a link to an external resource

Where do the data come from? Are you sure the color format is Formatyuv420planar?

@dev.bmax data come from imagereader camera2api android

When working with an external producer (e.g. camera) you cannot assume that the format is YUV 4:2:0 Planar. It can be either planar, semi-planar or packed planar.
You should ask the ImageReader what the format is and be ready to handle at least YUV_420_888, YUV_422_888, YUV_444_888.
Additionally, it's preferred to work with Image objects instead of ByteBuffers. The former contain all the necessary metadata (pixel stride, row stride, crop rect). MediaCodec supports Image both as input and output.
